# Watch a video at same time in JS

Tags: javascript, video, web, synchronization

Is it possible to create some code in js that would allow someone to watch a video at the same time as someone else. if you were to do this would you use sockets or would there be an easier way to show the video like in php or sql. I'm trying to create a web player that stays in sync with all the clients. So in total I'm trying to create a video that can be changed and also could be stopped and started at any time and would stay in sync with all the other ones

Comment: depends on definition of `same time`, usually it is impossible to achieve millisecond precision, seconds - probably

Comment: @Lashane well not at the exact same time just close to it if possible.

Comment: then websockets should be enough to transfer start/stop messages from/to clients

Comment: i keep getting a WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:25566/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED any fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With PHP + MySQL you can poll the server for a playStart event, say every second. Not perfect, but good enough. Your database will be the source of truth for all clients.

However I really recommend to do this via websockets, take a look into http://socket.io/ or http://meteor.com